# julia - How to find the key for the min/max value of a Dict?

Tags: dictionary, julia

I want to find the key corresponding to the min or max value of a dictionary in julia. In Python I would to the following:

```
my_dict = {1:20, 2:10}
min(my_dict, my_dict.get)
```

Which would return the key 2.

How can I do the same in julia ?

```
my_dict = Dict(1=>20, 2=>10)
minimum(my_dict)
```

The latter returns 1=>20 instead of 2=>10 or 2.

Comment: `indmin()` or `findmin()` should work. Don't know why `minimum()` does the wrong thing...

Comment: `findmin` doesn't work actually; it even gives a strange result in this case: `(1=>20,16)`

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders Strange, I get (10,2).

Comment: @daycaster `minimum` iterates `Pair`s, which compare lexicographically. Therefore, and because here the keys are unique, `minimum(x)` returns the contained `Pair` with the lowest key. And `indmin` returns the *index*, which is different from the *key*.

Comment: There is now an issue about this in the Julia repo: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/14672

Answer (score 8, accepted):

another option is:

```
collect(keys(d))[indmin(collect(values(d)))]
```

it depends on properties of keys and values iterators which are not guaranteed, but in fact work for Dicts (and *are* guaranteed for OrderedDicts). like the `reduce` answer, `d` must be non-empty.

why mention this, when the `reduce`, pretty much nails it? it is 3 to 4 times faster (at least on my computer) !

Comment: I think it should be guaranteed that the `keys` and `values` iterator return elements in the same order.  The order itself is undefined, but it'd be pretty crazy if they did something different from each other.

Comment: @MattB I don't think you should rely on this. As long as it's not documented, this is an implementation detail. But I agree that this *should* be guaranteed.

Comment: Let's document it, then.  Care to submit a pull request?

Comment: This can be written without the `collect`s, which will presumably be much faster: `d.keys[indmin(values(d))]`. However, `d.keys` is an internal data structure.

Comment: Is the inner `collect()` needed? I think this would work too: `collect(keys(d))[indmin(values(d))]` ;P

Comment: necroedit: As of Julia 1.0, `indmin()` is `argmin()`.

Answer (score 11):

You could use [`reduce`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/collections/#Base.reduce) like this, which will return the key of the first smallest value in `d`:

```
reduce((x, y) -> d[x] ≤ d[y] ? x : y, keys(d))
```

This only works for non-empty `Dict`s, though. (But the notion of the “key of the minimal value of no values” does not really make sense, so that case should usually be handled seperately anyway.)

---

*Edit regarding efficiency.*

Consider these definitions (none of which handle empty collections)...

```
m1(d) = reduce((x, y) -> d[x] ≤ d[y] ? x : y, keys(d))

m2(d) = collect(keys(d))[indmin(collect(values(d)))]

function m3(d)
  minindex(x, y) = d[x] ≤ d[y] ? x : y
  reduce(minindex, keys(d))
end

function m4(d)
  minkey, minvalue = next(d, start(d))[1]
  for (key, value) in d
    if value < minvalue
      minkey = key
      minvalue = value
    end
  end
  minkey
end
```

...along with this code:

```
function benchmark(n)
  d = Dict{Int, Int}(1 => 1)
  m1(d); m2(d); m3(d); m4(d); m5(d)

  while length(d) < n
    setindex!(d, rand(-n:n), rand(-n:n))
  end

  @time m1(d)
  @time m2(d)
  @time m3(d)
  @time m4(d)
end
```

Calling `benchmark(10000000)` will print something like this:

```
1.455388 seconds (30.00 M allocations: 457.748 MB, 4.30% gc time)
0.380472 seconds (6 allocations: 152.588 MB, 0.21% gc time)
0.982006 seconds (10.00 M allocations: 152.581 MB, 0.49% gc time)
0.204604 seconds
```

From this we can see that `m2` (from [user3580870's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33116139/4235730)) is indeed faster than my original solution `m1` by a factor of around 3 to 4, and also uses less memory. This is appearently due to the function call overhead, but also the fact that the λ expression in `m1` is not optimized very well. We can alleviate the second problem by defining a helper function like in `m3`, which is better than `m1`, but not as good as `m2`.

However, `m2` still allocates *O(n)* memory, which can be avoided: If you really need the efficiency, you should use an explicit loop like in `m4`, which allocates almost no memory and is also faster.

Comment: a version without unicode and working for empty `Dicts`:

    `reduce((x, y) -> (isa(x,Void) || (d[x] > d[y])) ? y : x, nothing, keys(d))`

Comment: Very nice comparison. I like the use of `next` to get the first value in the dictionary, even if the syntax is not elegant!

Comment: `d.keys[indmin(values(d))]` is very slightly slower than the explicit loop, but 3 times faster than the other short options. (However, `d.keys` is an internal data structure.)

Comment: Any idea, why isn't `m4` part of any julia library?

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to find Min with Key and Value

```
my_dict = Dict(1 => 20, 2 =>10)
```

`findmin(my_dict)` gives the output as below

```
(10, 2)
```

to get only key use

```
findmin(my_dict)[2]
```

to get only value use

```
findmin(my_dict)[1]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the minimum value, you can use

```
minimum(values(my_dict))
```

If you need the key as well, I don't know a built-in function to do so, but you can easily write it yourself for numeric keys and values:

```
function find_min_key{K,V}(d::Dict{K,V})

    minkey = typemax(K)
    minval = typemax(V)

    for key in keys(d)
        if d[key] < minval
            minkey = key
            minval = d[key]
        end
    end

    minkey => minval
end

my_dict = Dict(1=>20, 2=>10)

find_min_key(my_dict)
```

Comment: (I have removed my other comment as it is now obsolete.) But doesn't this have type-stability problems as well, for instance if `d::Dict{Int, Int}`? Isn't then the comparison between `Int` and either `Int` or `Float`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I thought you meant that the output of the function was not type stable, but you mean that `minkey` and `minval` change type *during* the function. I'll give it another go...

Comment: Thanks. Fixed to use `typemax`. This will work for any numeric types, but not e.g. for any kind of `String`s. It's surprisingly difficult to make this general! The `reduce` solution does work for that case, though.

Comment: Agreed, this is why I only consider the non-empty case in my solution ;).

Answer (score 2):

```
findmax(dict)[2]
findmin(dict)[2]
```

Should also return the key corresponding to the max and min value(s). Here [2] is the index of the key in the returned tuple.