# Julia find algorithm for general iterable collections

Tags: algorithm, julia

It seems to me there is no c++ style find algorithm applicable to a collection implementing a minimalistic subset of the iterable concept. I can only find functions designed to work on arrays etc. Is this an oversight (possibly mine!) or are there fundamental reasons not to include this in the standard library? I gave it a go and came up with something like this:

```
function findfirst(iter, value)
    findnext(iter, start(iter), value)
end

function findnext(iter, s, value)
    s0 = s
    while !done(iter, s0)
        item, s1 = next(iter, s0)
        if item == value
            return s0, true
        else
            s0 = s1
        end
    end

    return s0, false
end
```

It seems to work fine on Arrays, LinkedLists, and so on:

```
l = list(3,2,1,3)

s, found = findfirst(l,3)
while found
    item, s = next(l, s)
    @show item, s
    s, found = findnext(l, s, 3)
end

l = [3,2,1,3]
s, found = findfirst(l,3)
while found
    item, s = next(l, s)
    @show item, s
    s, found = findnext(l, s, 3)
end
```

Generating the following output:

```
(item,s) = (3,list(2, 1, 3))
(item,s) = (3,nil(Int64))
(item,s) = (3,2)
(item,s) = (3,5)
```

Comment: Maybe use [`findin(iter, elements)`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/collections/#Base.findin)?

Comment: The problem with `findin` is that it returns indices. When used on e.g. a list or another object not supporting random access it forces the caller to again iterate through the entire collection.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with dictionaries. Something similar came up recently in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111909/julia-how-to-find-the-key-for-the-min-max-value-of-a-dict/33112605#33112605

Comment: It is unclear of _why_ would you need this, other than replicate the c++ way of doing things. You can use functional aspects from julia to reproduce the same behaviour in different ways (`reduce` could accumulate results, you can use [tasks](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/control-flow/#tasks-aka-coroutines)...)

Comment: I am traversing a tree where branches on the same level are stored in a linked list. I need to find the branch that fulfils a certain condition. Next I descend a level and repeat. I am not claiming that this cannot be rewritten using existing Julia tools but saying that it is most natural or most readable is stretching it.

Comment: `filter(pred,iter)` with a `x->x==value` predicate returns an iterator with very similar functionality. To replicate example with list in OP, converting it to an iterator was required. one way is using `chain(...)` from `Iterators` package. together it becomes `flt = filter(x->x==3,chain(l))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since nobody is answering a question which is well hidden in the post, following is a suggestion, using standard packages (good practice). A shortcut macro/function can, of course, be defined for the `filter` notation:

```
using DataStructures,Iterators

l = list(3,2,1,3)
s = filter(x->x==3,chain(l))
for item in s
    @show item
end

l = [3,2,1,3]
s = filter(x->x==3,chain(l))
for item in s
    @show item
end
```

Output:

```
item = 3
item = 3
item = 3
item = 3
```